# Why can a free particle not exists in a stationary state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

In normalising the complete wavefunction of a free partcile; $V(x)=0$

we arrive at

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Psi_{k} ^\dagger\Psi_{k}dx=|A|^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx=|A|^{2}\left(\infty\right)$

Which implies that this wave function is not normalisable.

Mathematically, it is not normalisable but that's as far as my understanding goes. I would like to see a further and more related explanation for which a non-normalisable wave function implies that a free particle cannot exists in a stationary state and also that such a free particle does not have a definite energy.

Comment: These wave functions are perfectly normalizable, you are simply using the wrong math to do it. This has nothing to do with the question whether such a particle is stationary, or not, or whether it has a definite energy. A classical body doesn't have a definite energy, either. One can always add an arbitrary constant to a scalar potential without changing the physics and the kinetic energy is observer dependent.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you mean by 'wrong' math? Am I to use Fourier transform?

Comment: The proper mathematical tools that can do what you want can be found in "functional analysis" and Fourier transforms do fall under that discipline as a special application, but one can do much broader things with it, which is why physicists usually don't bother. We wing all of this by introducing a crude form of distribution with Dirac's delta function.

Comment: There are many existing questions that deal with this e.g. [Normalizing the solution to free particle Schrödinger equation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165373/normalizing-the-solution-to-free-particle-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation). Also [see this search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+normalise),  and similar searches using variations on *normalise*, *normalize*, *normalisation* etc.