# Particile with infinite lifetime still has spread in energy?

Tags: particle-physics

A particle with a lifetime $\tau$ and rest energy $E_0$ has a wavefunction, in natural units: $$ \psi(t) = \psi_0 e^{-iE_0 t} e^{-t/2\tau}.$$

The modulus squares of its Fourier transform $|\hat{\psi(E)}|^2$ gives the probability density of finding the particle at energy $E$:

$$ |\hat{\psi(E)}|^2 = \frac{\psi_0}{(E_0-E)^2 + \frac{1}{4\tau^2}}. $$

But if the particle has infinite lifetime, i.e. it is stable with $\tau \rightarrow \inf$, why does it still have a finite spread in energy space?

Comment: You forgot to normalize the function. If you include corresponding coefficient (depending on $\tau$) you would have a consistent limit $|\psi(E)|^2=\delta(E-E_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the $τ$ to infinity, the $Ψ$ becomes a plane wave solution of the corresponding basic quantum mechanical equation, (no potentials). [This cannot be normalized.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165373/normalizing-the-solution-to-free-particle-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation)

For the form you have, the modulus squared will just give $Ψ_0$ a constant saying that there is probability 1 to find the particle anyplace in space.
This is solved in quantum field theory, which is based on free particle solutions of the basic quantum mechanical equations, [by using wave packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Gaussian_wave_packets_in_quantum_mechanics), which are localized.