# Must a wavefunction be normalisable for a pdf to exist?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

My course notes say,

> for **normalised** wave functions $\psi(x,t)$, the function $$\rho(x,t)=|\psi(x,t)|^2=\overline{\psi(x,t)}\psi(x,t)$$ gives the $\color{red}{\text{probability density}}$ for the **position** of the particle.

I guessed from the bold that something about this is specific to normalised wave functions, but later the notes have

> The probability density of $$\psi(x,t)=A\exp(i(kx-\omega t))$$ is $$\rho(x,t)=|\psi|^2=|A|^2.$$ [...] We cannot normalise the wavefunction $\psi$.

So what relationship is there between normalisability and the existence of a probability density function? Can I use $\rho(x,t)=|\psi(x,t)|^2$ for any $\psi$, regardless of whether or not it's normalisable?

Comment: This may help - [Normalizing the solution to free particle Schrödinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165373/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks. I looked at that before posting, and a bit more closely just now, but I don't feel much clearer about what implicit assumptions my course notes might be making in order to write the pdf of a non-normalisable function without further comment. Just under my second quote the notes also write, "We can only talk about the *relative* probability of finding particle [sic] in two intervals" - but then what is meant by $\rho(x,t)=|\psi|^2=|A|^2$? Something like $$\frac{\rho(x,t)_{[a_1,b_1]}}{\rho(x,t)_{[a_2,b_2]}}=|A|^2\text{ for any }a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2\text{ s.t. }b_1-a_1=b_2-a_2?$$

Comment: It should really be $\rho/(region)$ = $A^2$.

Comment: is it bad that I originally thought this was asking about file types, and I was wondering why only certain files would require normalisable wavefunctions lol

Comment: @Tristan Because a .pdf file is in "*portable* document format", so I wondered if it might exist as a scattering state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use $\rho(x,t)=|\psi(x,t)|^2$ for any $\psi$, regardless of whether or not it's normalizable?

No. It has to be normalizable.

If you would like to consider a plane wave as a physical/normalizable solution, then the wavefunction can be forcibly normalized by putting the system inside a "box" of length $L$. In that case the normalization condition is
$$
1 = \int_0^L dx |\psi(x)|^2
$$
and you can set $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}$ in your plane waves and the probability density is constant
$$
\rho(x,t) = \frac{1}{L}
$$

Answer (score 4):

The probability distribution function is defined as $\rho$ = $\psi^* \psi$. It is integrated from the relevant bounds to find the probability in that region. Probability only makes sense when the probability for any event to occur is 100%. For example, if I roll a die, the probability that I get any number from 1 to 6 is 100%. Likewise, the probability that you find a particle anywhere should be 100%. This is why normalization occurs. When we have non normalizable functions, we can no longer talk about this “absolute” probability. Instead, something that people usually talk about is *relative* probability.

Let’s take a look at your function. $\rho = A^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx$ This is clearly divergent. Now what we can do is look at some finite region bounded by points $a$ and $b$. The integral over that region will give us $A^2V$ where $V$ is the volume over that region. Then you divide by that region to get $A^2$.

Now remember this isn’t really a probability distribution function. It’s more of trying to make the next best thing. You are dividing what *would* be the (non-normalizable!) function by some enclosed volume $V$ to get a finite expression.

Answer (score 2):

Any wave function that describes a particle must be normalizable. $\psi^*(\vec x)\psi(\vec x)$ is the probability density.

$$\int_{region} \psi^*(\vec x)\psi(\vec x) d \vec x$$

is the probability of finding the particle in the region. If the region is all space, the probability of finding it somewhere must be $1$.

A wave function that describes a particle can be built out of basis states that are not themselves suitable for such use. Plane waves are a common example of this.

A plane wave function cannot be normalized, except as a limiting case. The particle can be uniformly spread over all space. The probability of finding it in any finite region is $0$, The probability density at any point is $0$.

Using integration, you can add up infinite numbers of basis states with infinitesimal amplitudes in such a way that the sum is normalizable. The sum can be a wave function of a particle.

I haven't said anything new here. Maybe I have clarified things?

Comment: So in your terminology, unlike my course notes, $\psi(x,t)=A\exp(i(kx-\omega t))$ is a 'basis state' but not a 'wave function'?

Comment: It looks like your notes use $\psi$ for either. That is what I did too.

Comment: I'm thinking more of the statement "We cannot normalise the wavefunction" than of the use of $\psi$. This seems inconsistent with your "Any wave function must be normalizable.", no?

Comment: Good point. I clarified my wording.